# android how to load a specific Activity to access public methods

Tags: android, android-activity, public-method

i have a problem i don't want to load the current Activity like

```
 Activity currentActivity = getCurrentActivity();
```

i want to load another Activity...

```
TabActivity MainTabView = (TabActivity) getParent();
TabHost tabhost = MainTabView.getTabHost();
tabhost.setCurrentTab(1); // Artikelliste
Activity currentActivity = MainActivity; // what i want to load is called MainActivity (doesn't work)
((MainActivity) currentActivity).reload("22"); // Call the public function of MainActivity.
```

i want to reload the stuff in the Tab Activity 1. I switch to the tab and reload the stuff a listview controll.

i'm really new in android Development. I hope it's clear what i want :-)

the reload function of the MainActivity, i don't know if this works later for me.

```
 public void reload(String strCatID) {
        // Artikeldatenbank laden als Thread
        downloadJTLShopArtikeldatenbank("http://www.xyz.com/connector/jtl-shop-connector.php?modus=artikelliste&iCatID="+ strCatID);

        // Artikel öffnen im Shop
        lvwArtikel = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvwArtikelansicht);
        lvwArtikel.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int position, long arg)   {
                View grid;
                if (view == null) {
                    grid = null;
                } else {
                    grid = view;
                }
                // Abrufen aus dem aktiven Listview Eintrag (ArtikelID)
                TextView txtArtikelID = (TextView) grid.findViewById(R.id.txtArtikelID);

                // Neues Intent öffnen und die aktuelle Kategorie ID übergeben
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainItemsDetail.class);

                i.putExtra("iArtikelID", txtArtikelID.getText());
               /* tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("tab-2")
                        .setIndicator("Artikel")
                        .setContent(i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP))
                        .setContent(i)); */
                //.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP));

                startActivityForResult(i, 0);
            }
        });
    }
```

the MainTabView with the Tabs i needed

```
    final TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
    // Kategorieliste
    TabHost.TabSpec ts1 = tabHost.newTabSpec("tab-1");
    ts1.setIndicator("Kategorie");
    Intent intent1 = new Intent(MainTabView.this,MainCategory.class);
    //ts1.setContent(intent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP));
    ts1.setContent(intent1);
    tabHost.addTab(ts1);

    //progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainTabView.this, "",
    //        "Kategorien werden geladen");

    // Artikelliste
    TabHost.TabSpec ts2 = tabHost.newTabSpec("tab-2");
    ts2.setIndicator("Artikel");
    Intent intent2 = new Intent(MainTabView.this,MainActivity.class);
    //ts2.setContent(intent2.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP));
    ts2.setContent(intent2);
    tabHost.addTab(ts2);

    //progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainTabView.this, "",
    //        "Artikel werden geladen");

    // Warenkorb hinzufügen
    TabHost.TabSpec ts3 = tabHost.newTabSpec("tab-3");
    ts3.setIndicator("Warenkorb");
    Intent intent3 = new Intent(MainTabView.this,MainCart.class);
    //ts3.setContent(intent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP));
    ts3.setContent(intent3);
    tabHost.addTab(ts3);

    //progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainTabView.this, "",
    //        "Artikel werden geladen");
    tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new TabHost.OnTabChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
            Activity currentActivity = getCurrentActivity();
            if (currentActivity instanceof MainActivity) {
                ((MainActivity) currentActivity).reload("22");
            }
        }
    });
   }
```

sorry for the german comments in the code.

What i really want is to Switch from the MainCategoryTab to the MainActivityTab (item list), i want to react of the OnClick Event in the expanable listview. I want to switch to to MainActivity and reload the item list.

Answer (score 0):

If `MainActivity` is starting your current activity (`TabActivity`) you could use the [startActivityForResult()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29) / [setResult()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setResult%28int,%20android.content.Intent%29) methods. Here is an explanation of the workflow taken from the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#StartingActivities):

> Sometimes you want to get a result back from an activity when it ends.
>   For example, you may start an activity that lets the user pick a
>   person in a list of contacts; when it ends, it returns the person that
>   was selected. To do this, you call the startActivityForResult(Intent,
>   int) version with a second integer parameter identifying the call. The
>   result will come back through your onActivityResult(int, int, Intent)
>   method.
>
> When an activity exits, it can call setResult(int) to return data back
>   to its parent. It must always supply a result code, which can be the
>   standard results RESULT_CANCELED, RESULT_OK, or any custom values
>   starting at RESULT_FIRST_USER. In addition, it can optionally return
>   back an Intent containing any additional data it wants. All of this
>   information appears back on the parent's Activity.onActivityResult(),
>   along with the integer identifier it originally supplied.

While your activities are in the background they could be stopped and recreated once needed - the Android OS does this in order to optimize memory usage. Thus it is not possible to rely on reference to your parent activity since it could change.

If you could add the source code for your `MainActivity` and `TabActivity`, I could help you with the changes you'd need to make.

Comment: ok, i have extended the source code. i hope it helps to understand the problem.

Answer (score 0):

i've tried a new way with getLocalActivityManager.getActivity() but it throws a null pointer. 
To Call getLocalActivityManager i had to be a ActivityGroup.

```
        Activity currentActivity = (MainActivity) getLocalActivityManager().getActivity("MainActivity");
        ((MainActivity) currentActivity).reload(txtCatID.getText().toString());
```

i think its the wrong way to do this.